# Weibull with time-dependent outcome

Tags: r, weibull

I am trying to run Weibull model for longitudinal measurements .i.e. Weibull with time-dependent outcome. I found the following functions in library("eha") R. I am not sure if can add `cluster(ID)` to these functions? If the answer is no, then how can I fit the model?  What are the difference between these functions?

```
fit1=aftreg(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ x1+x2+x3+cluster(ID),dist="weibull"
    ,param = "lifeExp", data = df)

fit2=phreg(Surv(start,stop, event) ~ x1+x2+x3+cluster(ID),dist = "weibull" 
    ,data =df)


fit3=weibreg(Surv(start,stop, event) ~ x1+x2+x3+cluster(ID) ,data =nadf)
```

Comment: This has no data and it's primarily a request for statistical advice. I can withdraw my vote to migrate to CrossValidated.com if it's [edit]-ed to bring in a sample dataset and remove the request for statistical tutoring.